# Cherry Framework - Jquery Update

Tags: jquery, frameworks

My theme is based in Cherry Framework 3.1.5 and Jquery 1.7.2 and I'm using a very important plugin that needs Jquery 1.9 or avobe.

How can I update/migrate my Jquery 1.7 to a higher version?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer was published over here although with no explanation at all. You have to disable the JQuery that comes with Cherry Framework adding the following code to your `functions.php` file (under your theme folder):

```
// Remove themes old version of jQuery and load a compatible version
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'update_jquery_for_cherry_framework', 11);
function update_jquery_for_cherry_framework() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', false, false, true);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

What the code does is (line by line):

1. Load the function update_jquery_for_cherry_framework
2. Deregister the jquery script
3. Registrer the jquery script from the following file /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js
4. Load the just registered jquery script

I had an incompatibility that produced an error while updating the WooCommerce cart (removing or updating quantity of products) and now is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'update_jquery_for_cherry_framework', 11);

function update_jquery_for_cherry_framework() {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('jquery', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', false, false, true);

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Comment: Surely you could add more text to explain your answer.